# What font is used for Romaniuk Heating & Air Conditioning's logo?

Tags: font-identification

[image: Logo]

Please help me identify the font with the unique capital A.

Update:
This font is also believed to have been used for the Stranger Things title sequence

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Looks to me like [**ITC Benguiat Bold**](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/adobe/itc-benguiat/bold/).

[image: ROMANIUK]

This was picked up right away by [WhatTheFont](http://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/). I recommend taking a look at our [font-identification wiki page](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info) for some resources to identify fonts.

Comment: This is the Times Roman of 70s fiction softcovers

Comment: @horatio not 70s, but I immediately recognized it as the font used for [Hyperion](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/73/Hyperion_cover.jpg). Giving it a bit more thought and I realized it's the font for the "[Choose Your Own Adventure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/RYP1m.jpg)" books. Nice observation :)